# Excluding characters in group (regular expressions)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an issue with regular expressions in Javascript (I'm not a pro in regular expressions matters).

For reasons that I don't explain, I have to match a text in a certain way and I cannot change the code who deals with the result.

For example, I want to match this text: Mon.2014/01/01
In a way to obtain this result: ["Mon.", "20140101"]
and this only with a regex and no post processing.

I tried with lookaheads, excluding groups, noticed that there are not lookbehinds and lookarounds and I didn't manage to solve it.

EDIT: I put a code sample so it is easier to understand what I'm doing.

```
function match(regexes, text) {
    for(var i in regexes) {
        var match = text.match(regexes[i]);
        if(match !== null) {
             return match;    
        }
    }
}
// expected result of match(regexes, "Mon.2014/01/01"): ["Mon.","20140101"]
```

How I told you, I cannot change the code, so this has to be done solely with a regex.
Does anyone have some hint?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't see an actual question here - the specification of your problem is incomplete.

Comment: what about negative lookahead: `^(?!.*ab).*$`

Comment: HasanAboShally sorry, in which way that should make me have the string "Mon." in the first group and "10240101" in the second one?

Alnitak: how is it incomplete? I gave the input and the output expected. I would like to have a solution to match the input obtaining the output
var re = /a regex here.../
"Mon.2014/01/01".match(re) --result-->  ["Mon.", "20140101"] 

and in top of that I would like to understand the concept so I can reproduce it any time that I want exclude characters from the matching without having to create multiple groups.

Comment: Ok, so can you modify the `text` param to this `match` function as well?

Comment: Nope. Only the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **You can't.**

If the code uses String.match method, it only returns the parts of the strings that matched your regexp.  You can't embed string modifications inside a match regexp, for that you would have to do a replace.

Two possible solutions to work around your issue:

1. Inject some javascript before this particular code is ran, and override the String.prototype.match method to split your regexp text into 2 separate regexp's, one that does .replace and one that does the .match  -- in this way you add support in your database to be able to alter strings before matching.  If no delimiter is found, it defaults to original match method.
2. Find an alternative to your requirement to modify the string.  Rather than expecting ["Mon.","20140101"], expect ["Mon.","2014/01/01"].. because that's what is there.  Now if you need a regexp to match either format, that's certainly possible, but it will always return whatever is actually there that it matched on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var s = "Mon.2014/01/01";
var result = s.replace(/\//g,'').match(/((?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri)\.)(\d{8})/).slice(1);
// result => ["Mon.", "20140101"]
```

Comment: Then you can't do what you're wanting. You can't get the results you are asking for using a single regular expression, regardless of using lookahead or lookbehind features.  If you can change the regular expression, then presumably you could use the solution above, as it on inserts a `replace()` call between the string and the call to `match()`. Can you explain what you can modify?  If it's only the regular expression, then I think you are at a loss.

Comment: I can indeed modify only the regular expression. The example i posted (with the example test to match also) are just a mock of what I have to do, it is actually more complicated. I cannot change the code for motivations that nothing have to do with software engineering, just tell you this :) If I cannot match this text with a regex, I will not match this text.

Comment: The only way I see of doing this, is the same route. `'Mon.2014/01/01'.replace(/\//g, '').match(/^(\D+)(.*)$/).slice(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Your "change the code" criteria is very confusing.  You are on a site for code help.  But it sounds like "How do i code X without code?"

Help us better understand your situation here.  Is it because the regex that is going to be used comes from a database?  And you can only modify the contents of a database?  Or maybe a 'regex' web service?  It seems that it's confusing to many of us, so please add some context so we can help you with a solution.

Comment: Ok. The text is in a web page (every possible web page). The regexes are in a database. I can modify the database to add regexes but not the code with the logic. I really cannot say more about this.

Comment: This should be a comment to the questions, not an answer.

Comment: Figured it had to be a database regex fetch.

Comment: And goofed up and hit answer instead of comment.  I agree it was a comment.